# Has many :through, a better way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

I've set up a threaded message system, similar to facebook, where one user has many conversations going on simultaneously. Each of these conversations has a unique group of people involved and each contains multiple messages.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :involvements
  has_many :conversations, through: :involvements, unique: true
end
```

---

```
class Involvement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :involvable, polymorphic: true
end
```

---

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :involvements, as: :involvable
  has_many :participants, through: :involved, class_name: "User", unique: true
  has_many :messages
end
```

---

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

I got it working with this, but I can't help feeling like there has to be some better, more efficient way to condense this setup, for example use 3 models. or maybe using a habtm with unique columns or something...

Four models to send a message just seems like too many. Any suggestions? Or is this something I shouldn't be worrying about?

Comment: Why does 4 seem like too many? There are 4 pieces of data that play into this: The users, their participation in conversations, the conversations, and the messages within those conversations. Your setup looks perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many), It might be a way for you to be able to get rid of one of those models.